# Expression for labeling line start and end points

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

I have a multi line string vector layer, on the map they display as straight horizontal lines and I want to display the label at the start and end point of the lines on the map.
What’s the best expression to use for this?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 3):

The capability to label line start or end locations has only been added a few days ago, so you'll need to use the current development version:

https://north-road.com/2020/09/03/line-label-placement-our-gift-to-the-qgis-community/

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use a geometry generator to locate the label at start (or end) point of the lines, using the expression `start_point($geometry)` and  `end_point($geometry)`

[image]